# Galois field extension and number of intermediate fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field

Given the galois extension $L/K$, where $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta, \sqrt[3]{2})$. I've already calculated that $[L:\mathbb{Q}]=6$. I'm trying to prove that the number of intermediate fields is also 6, including $L$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ as intermediate fields. I'm told that the fundamental theorem of galois theory can be useful here, but I can't find a use for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint**:

What is the Galois group $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$?

Well, the minimal polynomial for which $L$ is a splitting field is $f(x) = x^3 - 2$, which has roots $\sqrt[3]{2}, \zeta \sqrt[3]{2}$, and $\zeta^2 \sqrt[3]{2}$.  It is useful to remember that each element of the Galois group is uniquely determined by its action on the roots of $f$.

Now, complex conjugation is always a legitimate $\mathbb{Q}$-automorphism.  That is, $\phi(\zeta) = \overline{\zeta}$.  Further, I claim that another automorphism $\tau$ is defined by $\sqrt[3]{2} \mapsto \zeta\sqrt[3]{2}$.  Can you prove this?

What happens when we take powers of $\phi$ and $\tau$ and compose them with each other?  For me, it is especially illuminating to view the roots of $f$ as vertices of a triangle in the complex plane and see how these automorphisms are acting on it.

---

**Alternative path**:

It is a theorem that the Galois group will be a subgroup of the symmetric group acting on the roots of $f$.  Therefore, we know $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q}) \leq S_3$.  However, we also know that $|\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})| = [L:\mathbb{Q}] = 6$, so that certainly narrows down the possibilities for $\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$!

---

Once you've determined the Galois group, then what are its subgroups?  Remember the fundamental theorem tells us that there is a one-to-one correspondence between subgroups of the Galois group and intermediate fields of the Galois extension.

Comment: Right. Count the subgroups, you’ve counted the intermediate fields, including the top and the bottom.

Comment: I've calculated the galois group to be $S_3$, and according to the fundamental theorem of galois theory, I know that there's a bijection from subgroups of the galois group and the intermediate fields. so number of subgroups of galois group = number of intermediate fields. What I need to show now is that number of subgroups of galois group=6, but there's more than 6 subgroups of $S_3$, right?

Comment: Nope!  There are only $6$.  Two of them are simply $\{id\}$ and $S_3$ itself.  What are the other $4$?  Hint: Lagrange's theorem tells us they will be of order $2$ or of order $3$.

Comment: ah I see, thanks

Comment: Glad I could help!