# Find the intermediate fields of the extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

I got the question from one of the previous old exam sheets, but I couldn't be sure to determine it. Let $\alpha=\sqrt[3]2$ and $\epsilon=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{3}}$(a primitive third root of 1) and let $K=\Bbb{Q}[\alpha,\epsilon]$. Find the intermediate fields of the extension $K$ over $\Bbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Galois group is given by $S_3$, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56804/galois-group-of-x3-2-over-mathbb-q). By the Galois correspondence it is enough to find the subgroups of $S_3$. This has been solved [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/531202/how-many-distinct-subgroups-does-the-symmetric-group-s-3-have). Then  you obtain all intermediate fields.

Edit: I found that the question was already answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1041800/galois-field-extension-and-number-of-intermediate-fields?rq=1).

Comment: ..It is not exactly the same, but I am trying to understand it by considering complex elements.

Comment: It is exactly the same since $\epsilon=\zeta=e^{2\pi i/3}$.

Comment: ohhhh... I see . Thanks!